# Hill cipher cryptanalysis - known plaintext known key size

Tags: classical-cipher, known-plaintext-attack, key-size, hill-cipher, matrix-multiplication

Hello I want to know how to go about this problem
I know the plaintext "abcdef" and the ciphertext. The key size is 2.
I really can't figure out how to find the key for decrypting and encrypting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k=\left(\begin{array}{cc}k_0 & k_1\\k_2 & k_3\end{array}\right)$ be the key. And I'll assume the transformation $a=0$, $b=1$, and so on.

So you know $k\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}c_0\\c_1\end{array}\right)$ where you know $c_0$ and $c_1$.

Thus $c_0=0k_0+1k_1$ and $c_1=0k_2+1k_3$. So that is two equations, 4 unknowns. Can't be solved yet. But you have more data which gives you $c_2=2k_0+3k_1$, $c_3=2k_2+3k_3$, $c_4=4k_0+5k_1$ and $c_5=4k_2+5k_3$. Now you have 6 equations and 4 unknowns. Setup a system of linear equations and solve. That will give you the $k_i$ values for your key. The decryption key is just the inverse.

*Remember that the math is done modulo 26.*

You won't always be able to solve the system of linear equations, but you likely have enough plaintext ciphertext pairs to get it done. Using the PT/CT pairs in the comments, for example, you would end up with the following equations for $k_0,k_1$.

$$
\begin{align*}
2k_0+17k_1&=11\\
24k_0+15k_1&=3\\
19k_0+14k_1&=3
\end{align*}
$$

From there, my preferred method is to take two of the equations, build an augmented matrix and put it in reduced row echelon form. So you'd first have

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}19&14&3\\2&17&11\end{array}\right)$$

Instead of doing all the math, I'll just get you started. Start by multiplying the first row by $19^{-1}=11$. Then you would have

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}1&24&7\\2&17&11\end{array}\right)$$

Then you want to get rid of the $2$ on the second row, so do $row_2=row_2-2row_1$. Eventually you'll be in the right form and have $k_0$ and $k_1$. Repeat this process for $k_2$ and $k_3$. For this one it will work out. If you had started with the $3=24k_0+15k_1$ row on top, you may have gotten stuck since $24$ has no inverse. So if you get stuck (needing to invert something that is non-invertible), try a different equation or a different set of elementary row operations.

Comment: How do I solve the linear equations? I have tried choosing some equations and solve for k0 and then find if it has a multiplicative inverse. But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you post the cipher texts? Also are you sure the math is done mod 26 (that was my assumption)?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is mod 26.
Another example is m = 2, 17, 24, 15, 19, 14. c = 11, 18, 3, 10, 3, 7. Try this example :-) and thanks

Comment: @cryptonoob123 because I didn't know if this was homework or not, I didn't want to give a complete answer. Hopefully this helps at least.